# Is it safe to use a raw pointer to a QObject as a signal argument?

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, qt5

The qt [doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpointer.html) says:

> it is of little value to declare functions to take a QPointer as a
>   parameter; just use normal pointers. Use a QPointer when you are
>   storing a pointer over time.

But is it safe to use a normal pointer to a QObject as a signal parameter too?

What happens if the signal is connected to a slot with `Qt::QueuedConnection` and the parameter object gets detroyed before the slot had been invoked?

```
class MyObject : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit MyObject(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) {}

signals:
  void mySignal_A(QObject *parameter);
  void mySignal_B(QPointer<QObject> parameter);
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s not safe to pass a pointer as argument in a queued signal/slot connection, if the object pointed to might be deleted meanwhile as you already suspect. I think the documentation is referring to synchronous function calls (which also applies to direct connections).

You can use QPointer or QSharedPointer/QWeakPointer (or C++11’s std::shared_ptr/std::weak_ptr). Shared pointers are only safe to use though if the QObject has no parent.

Even better, avoid passing around QObjects if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It will behave exactly the same, as calling normal member with invalid pointer. If you're using this QObject in slot then you'll get UB - however you could use QWeakPointer instead of raw QObject pointer to control if your QObject was destroyed in another context